# Codeigniter onchange event for dynamically created view selectboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and need some help. In my controller I get data for my options and suboption and load the view in the following code. The view basically just creates a table that consists of the select boxes passed to it from the controller. The issue I am having is that I am not sure how to do an onchange event for dynamically generated controls.

```
<?php foreach($options as $option) { ?>
       <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><p><?php echo $option['name']; ;?>:</p></td>
       <td>
       <select name="<?php echo $option['name']; ?>" id="<?php echo $option['name']; ?>" rows="4" class="form-control">                     
          <?php foreach($suboptions as $suboption) { ?>
             <?php if($suboption['plat_option'] ==  $option['name']) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $suboption['name']; ?>"><?php echo $suboption['name']; ?></option>
             <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </td> 
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

To go into a little more detail, I would like the onchange event to look at the selected suboption and check the other selectboxes to see if they contain the same suboption. If another select box does have that suboption, it would then be disabled so it could not be picked twice.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code will helps you

```
<?php foreach($options as $option) { ?>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><p><?php echo $option['name']; ;?>:</p></td>
   <td>
   <select name="<?php echo $option['name']; ?>" id="<?php echo $option['name']; ?>" rows="4" class="form-control" onchange="change(this.value)">                     
      <?php foreach($suboptions as $suboption) { ?>
         <?php if($suboption['plat_option'] ==  $option['name']) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $suboption['name']; ?>"><?php echo $suboption['name']; ?></option>
         <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </td> 
  </tr>
```

javascript function

```
 function change(val)
{
alert(val)
}
```